# Passing Bluemix APP-ID authentication from Node.js to Angular5

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, app-id

I'm working on a project that uses Bluemixes APP-ID for authentication and are using Node.js for our backend. What I want to do is to be able to login with the App-ID authentication (that uses passport.js) and use this token in my Angular5 project and from there be able to store new user-specific attributes.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Thankful for any answers :)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it seems like the way forward is to create an endpoint in the Node.js that one then uses with the angular project. Just make sure the endpoint also is protected by the webAppStrategy if using that.